# Python - Data for mysql with dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dataframe, database-migration

I'm new to Python and I wanted to ask you for help.

I want to put the data of a view in SQL Server into a table of my database in MySQL, when I try to give the following error:

> Execution failed on sql: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE
>   type='table' AND name=?; not all arguments converted during string
>   formatting unable to rollback

Using Python version 3.7

Below is the code I use:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

# SQL Server Connection
connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLServer")  #autocommit=True

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        result = "SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_sale"
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_sale", connection)
        cursor.execute(result)
        table = cursor.fetchall()
        print(table)
finally:
    connection.close()


# MySQL connection
cnx = pymysql.connect(host='test',
                      user='test',
                      password='test',
                      db='dw')    

try:
    with cnx.cursor() as cursor:
        mysql = "select *from ft_sale_test"
        cursor.execute(mysql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        #print(result)
finally:
    cnx.close()   
# using if_exists to handle the table that already exists
```

> The error happens right here

```
 df.to_sql(con=cnx, name= 'ft_sale_test', if_exists= 'replace')
```

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond with your error.

Comment: post a stacktrace please

Comment: I just checked the two has the same number of columns

Comment: missing a _ no df.to_sql so the error I mentioned above persists